# Expression isn't computed correctly

Tags: c++, overflow

I wrote this code that has evaluated everything correctly until this specific set of numbers :

```
#include <cmath>

int n1 = 187972 ;
int n2 = 12026 ;
double a = 0.002 ;
int partial = round((n1*n2)*a) ;
int result = n1 - partial ;
```

result is returned by the program as 4256804, which is completely wrong. I suppose I am mistaken,but I cannot see how.

Comment: Looks like `n1*n2` overflows an `int`.

Comment: `2260551272` > `2147483647` (aka `INT_MAX`)

Comment: Note that there are several ways to avoid the overflow: https://godbolt.org/z/6xsKW6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as in the comments suggested, the result is correct because n1*n2 is overflowing the int max value generating a negative number as result from an overflow

actually `-2034416024`

here ideone so you can verify

https://ideone.com/NIGCmx

a solution could be use long numbers instead

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "correct". Overflowing an `int` is UB. Wrap around is not required (at least until c++20 iirc).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cmath>

int n1 = 187972 ;
int n2 = 12026 ;
double a = 0.002 ;
long long partial = round((n1*n2)*a) ;   // new
long long result = n1 - partial ;   // new
```